# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password :YES)

Tags: php, mysql, laragon

I have downloaded Laragon and i click `Menu-> Quick app->WordPress` and then it asks to give a name . So I give one and then I click ok.

After that i have this error:

> Reason: mysqladmin:[Warning] Using a password on the command line inerface can be insecure. mysqladmin:Unknown OS character set 'cp737'. mysqladmin:Switching to the default character set 'latin1' mysqladmin:connect to server at 'localhost' failed error:'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password :YES)

ps: i have tried to create new root code.

Does anyone knows something ?

Comment: I'm not certain but I *think* it might be that MySQL doesn't support the CP737 (Greek?) character set (collation), so it's falling over when juggling it to 8859-1 on the username/password - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: i don't know what to do to sollve it..